# How can I get Piwik log importer to run faster on Windows / IIS?

Tags: iis, matomo, windows-server-2012

I've got Piwik set up on Windows Server 2012 and I'm importing about 20Gb of historical log files, spread across 10 different sites.

I've merged my log files for each site into several huge text files, since a wildcard import isn't possible on Windows.

The import process is taking ages, and I'm currently only getting about **25 records/sec** on a quad-core server with 16Gb RAM.

How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the key to speeding up Piwik log importing on Windows is the **--recorders** setting.

The Piwik documentation recommends about the same number of recorders as CPU cores on the server, but I think this assumes that the CPU is the bottleneck. In my case I'm only getting about 5% CPU utilisation, so clearly something else is holding things up. I suspect it's my PHP / IIS / MySQL setup, because the Piwik front end is a bit sluggish as well.

I've added **--recorders=64** and now I'm getting a much more respectable **170 records/sec**.

This still feels a bit slow though, so any other suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running this on Windows, but I got some I got some nice performance improvements by adjusting the Mysql InnoDB settings:

```
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 256K
thread_cache_size = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
sync_binlog = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

Be careful though, some of these settings affect safety. I'm currently running at about 1000 records/second using 8 recorders on a quad core i5 with 16 GB RAM with only a single disk for Mysql.

My configuration is using Apache 2.2 with mod_fcgid running PHP using the command line client. I'm also using [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29) to cache the compiled PHP code. Mysql is v5.5. All running on Ubuntu 12.10.